# Embed same web widget multiple times with different data attribute values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create **a web widget** that can be **embedded multiple times** on the **same page** but with different data attribute values so I can display different data according to the data attribute value.

For example, I want to embed mywidget.js file multiple times as follows:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <script src="script/mywidget.js" data-sport="soccer" id="widget-soccer">
        </script>
    </div> 

    <div>
        <script src="script/mywidget.js" data-sport="tennis" id="widget-tennis">
        </script>
    </div> 
</body>
```

My question is, inside the code in mywidget.js, how do I determine the correct script tag reference and read it's data attribute so I can use that value  to fetch the corresponding data from a web service. I am using only jquery and javascript.

I want the widget to be embeddable on other users sites as well so all they do is embed using only the script tag and passing in the desired data attribute value without adding anything extra anywhere they need on their website.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a very good approach, as it is very inflexible. But given that `<script>` tags, when not deferred, halt parsing of the document while they execute, the current script tag will be the last in the DOM; so you can get the current sport inside your script by using this:

```
var sport = $('script').last().data('sport');
```

However, it would be much better to define a function in your external JavaScript file, and then invoke it when you need to instantiate your widget (EDIT: like in Lee Taylor's answer).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like:

```
<head>
    <script src="script/mywidget.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div><script>createMyWidget({sport : "soccer"} );</div> 

    <div><script>createMyWidget({sport : "tennis"} );</div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can. I know it's not that nice, but I would try:

```
<div><script>sport = "soccer";</script><script src="script/mywidget.js"  id="widget-soccer"></script></div> 

<div><script>sport = "tennis";</script><script src="script/mywidget.js" id="widget-tennis"></script></div>
```

and use sport in mywidget.js

Another approach could be that myscript.js is actually a dynamic "page", let's say with php, then you could use src="script/mywidget.js?sport=swimming", and in the php you would print:

```
sport = "<?php echo addcslashes($_GET['sport'], '"'); ?>";
```

But even better would be:

```
<script src="script/mywidget.js"></script>    
<div><script>showWidget("soccer");</script></div>
<div><script>showWidget("basketball");</script></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use jQuery to find all script tags with src="script/mywidget.js" or something

```
$('script[src="script/mywidget.js"]')
```

And then you'll have an array of scripts tags that you can loop through and access the `data` property using jQuery's `.data()` method.